# Slideshow for multiple attachments in android messaging application

Tags: android, messaging, slideshow, attachment

Please guide me to achieve this :

I want to create slideshow for multiple attachment in my messaging application, user can attach image, audio and video files.

For single attachment user can view file directly and when user is attaching more files, application should create a playable slideshow and later he can edit the slide show as well, same like messaging application in android.

The slide-show functionality same like below :

Compose Message :

[image: Compose Message]

Add attachment :

[image]

Add another attachment :

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want someone to design your program. What do you mean exactly by "messaging application".

Comment: @Charles - Yes i want to that how i can achieve this ?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want to know how to achieve the layout or design like WhatsApp ? With text messages and attachments like images, videos and audio files!

Comment: Like: https://androidmarket.googleusercontent.com/android/market/com.whatsapp/ss-480-2-14

Comment: @Bartinger - When we select multiple attachments during messaging it converts it into slide-show.

Answer (score 0):

I not really sure what you mean by slideshow, but I think the ViewPager. It's used in the Market app, GTalk and Google+ app. You can add different Views and navigate through them programmatically or through swiping with your finger.
You can find a lot of resources on the Internet for example:
http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html

Comment: Edited question please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I would use ViewPager for the attachments (The view under the 3 buttons) then you can swipe between multiple attachments

Comment: Thanks for your response but i am not talking here about the view, the concern is how this playable slideshow is created as and when we add second attachment.

Comment: Ok I think I finally get what you mean :) The slideshow thing confused me a little. Just the image part should be the slideshow and when you have multiple attachments you want these images, videos (thumbnails) and audio files as a slideshow. Correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly! for more you can try messaging in your device with multiple attachments. The slideshow is the combined file (we can say) which could be played having text message, audio, video and image files also it could be edited. That's what i am trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: You could still use the ViewPager for the attachments. But then you have just this one slide animation.